# User permissions to /system files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, middleware

What is the best route to accomplish the following.

Let's say in my rails application I have folders:

```
/system/cms/attachments
/system/attachments/
/system/attachments/Project
/system/attachments/Meeting
```

Files are uploading into these folders and are web accessible. At this time I want to add some permissions to access them. If someone tries to access `myapp/system/attachments/meetings/doc1.docx` I want to ensure they are authenticate with the application. For another `myapp/system/attachments/Project/doc2.docx` I may want to check that the user has a certain role.

My thought was to setup some Rack Middleware to accomplish this, when I did this my middleware appears to handle all my requests expect for those is /system

Is there a configuration setting I can change to allow my Middleware to also interact with /system paths.

Is there a better, easier way to accomplish what I'm looking to do?
Essentially a route or something if path is like '/system/attachment/project/' run this block of logic. This logic may be somewhat complex and will require access to models and environment stuff.  It will then ultimately return the response of the file content or fail/redirect to insufficient permissions.

Appreciate your thoughts and dialog on this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better, and simpler to implement, to accomplish this by associating your uploads to a model and applying permissions to the models which will be used to initiate downloads.

**Implementation overview**

- Use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to upload files and associate them with a Model e.g. `Attachment`

  - This will make it easy for users to upload files. A record will be created for each upload. The model will store the file_name and you'll be able to call `@attachment.url` to get the URL of the file to download for the user.
- Use [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to implement permissions on the `Attachment` model.

**User's Workflow**

- The user will be able to upload files, or the admin can manually upload files.
- Each upload will save an `Attachment` record to the db with a reference to the path where the file was uploaded to (Paperclip let's you configure this path so you can set it to your /system path.
- Show the users an index of `Attachment`'s i.e. `GET /attachments` and when the user clicks to download one, your app will receive a request at `GET /attachments/1`
- Your controller will find it: `@attachment = Attachment.find params[:id]`
- Now you can do the permission check: `authorize! @attachment, :read` (this will be based off [rules you set up in an ability.rb file](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities))
- You can also choose to only display `attachment`s that the user is allowed to see: `@attachments = Attachment.accessible_by current_ability` see https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records
- If an `AccessDenied` error was raised (because the user didn't have permission for this attachment) then catch the error and render a flash message or something, otherwise
- Your controller will then initiate the download using [send_data](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) or [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) e.g. `send_file @attachment.url, filename: @attachment.attachment_file_name, disposition: 'attachment'`

This approach leverages existing upload and permissions libraries to accomplish your goal with minimal code on your part. An additional benefit is that users will never see the actual URL of the uploaded file, they will only see resourceful paths (e.g. /attachments/1) and you won't have to publicly expose your /system directory, which is a very good idea.